# Knockout js: How can i push to an observable array that has been mapped

Tags: knockout.js

i have an observable array called FriendsOnline in my Onlinefriends model which was mapped, and i want to add a new item inside it. this was initially what i tried.

```
onlineFriends.addFriend = ko.computed(function () {

    socket.on('friend joined', function(data) {

        var mapping = {
            'friendsOnline': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new friendModel(data);
                }
            }
        };

        onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

        console.log(onlineFriends.friendsOnline());

    });

});
```

but i get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return firstName() }"
Message: firstName is not defined` and i know it is as a result of me using foreach on the array and calling the

`data-bind="text:firstName()` in the HTML page

like this: `

```
            <li class="online" data-bind="click:$parent.startChat" >
              <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left profile-photo" href="">
                  <img class="media-object" src="assets/images/ici-avatar.jpg" th:alt="alt"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h6 class="media-heading"><span data-bind="text:firstName()">Ing. Imrich </span></h6>
                  <small><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span data-bind="text:country()">Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia</span></small>
                  <span class="badge badge-outline status"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>`
```

this is what the json data i get looks like :

```
{"firstName":"Mfon","id":"2","address":"vgc","bio":"A man’s gotta make at least one bet a day, else he could be walking around lucky and never know it.","country":"Macau S.A.R.","email":"mfon@gmail.com","firstname":"Mfon","gender":"FEMALE","lastname":"Ukim","locked":false,"money":0,"onlinestatus":"ONLINE","password":"mfon","phonenumber":"08023182388","picture":"generic-avatar.jpg","username":"mfon","usertype":"PLAYER"}
```

based on my understanding i feel the item i receive from the socket, its fields are not properly mapped into observables, but they are just pushed into the array. so they cannot be called. Please can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

this line  *onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data))* - should works fine and add new observable to observable array.

Few things to pay attention:

- if u want to use mapping when doing fromJS operation u need to specify this is call. In your case this would be:  onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping));
- and check parent context in html where u use firstName, common problem is that it migth be not the one u expected.
- and when u use binding in HTML u can specify observables without (), like data-bind = "text: $data.firstName". In that case this line will work fine for both observables and simple values
- btw, u have 2 similar props "firstName" and "firstname" in your json

What does this line prints in your case?  *console.log(onlineFriends.friendsOnline());* If this prints correct data with all observables, than you definetely have issue with binding context in html

Comment: yes it prints correct the with all the observables in, in my onlineFriends Model

Comment: then i posted this question afterwards, because i found out that knockout was pushing an extra non observable item into the array      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714491/knockout-why-does-my-computed-function-push-items-into-my-observable-array-auto

Comment: btw, how do and where do i add the new observable to the observable array

Comment: are u asking me where in your code u push new observable to the observable array???

Comment: no i am not, sorry lemme rephrase the question, the array automatically pushes the data i get from the socket into the array alongside the data i converted to an observable, why is this ?

Comment: i've created js fiddle based on your data and I see 1 item in an array. That is not actually correct (coz of wrong usage of context, as was anwered in your 2nd question), but still item in array is single. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/oshumelyuk/Lfm47vb2/4/

Comment: try to move listener socket.on out of your computed function, maybe it called twice, so you have 2 socket listeners instead of one..