# knockout: why does my computed function push items into my observable array automatically ?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed function, that gets data from a websocket call and pushes it into my observable array

```
onlineFriends.friendIsOnline = ko.computed(function () {

    socket.on('friend joined', function(data) {

        console.log(data);

        var newObservableItem = onlineFriends.friend(data);

        console.log(newObservableItem);

        onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(newObservableItem);

        console.log(onlineFriends.friendsOnline())


    });

});
```

this is the function that converts it into an observable :

```
onlineFriends.friend = function(data) {

    var self = this;

    self.country = ko.observable(data.country);

    self.firstName = ko.observable("oto");

    self.userName = ko.observable(data.username);

    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);

    self.picture = ko.observable(data.picture);

    self.hasInitMessage = ko.observable(false);

    self.messages =  ko.observableArray([]);

    return self;


};
```

this is the data i receive from socket listener:

{"firstName":"Mfon","id":"2","address":"vgc","bio":"A man’s gotta make at least one bet a day, else he could be walking around lucky and never know it.","country":"Macau S.A.R.","email":"mfon@gmail.com","firstname":"Mfon","gender":"FEMALE","lastname":"Ukim","locked":false,"money":0,"onlinestatus":"ONLINE","password":"mfon","phonenumber":"08023182388","picture":"generic-avatar.jpg","username":"mfon","usertype":"PLAYER"}

the data from the socket is supposed to be converted into an observable and pushed inside the Observable array, but instead the data itself is pushed into the observable array along with the new observable data, making to items present in my observable array, why is this ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `friend()` method isn't returning what you think it does. You intended it to be a "friendFactory" but instead it's returning the entire `onlineFriends` array and that's because your `this` refers to the `onlineFriends` array.

Try to change your method to behave more like a factory/mapping-to-observable instead:

```
onlineFriends.makeFriend = function(data) {
    return {
        country: ko.observable(data.country),
        firstName: ko.observable("oto"),
        userName: ko.observable(data.username),
        id: ko.observable(data.id),
        picture: ko.observable(data.picture),
        hasInitMessage: ko.observable(false),
        messages: ko.observableArray([])
    };
};
```

Then in your socket listener:

```
var newObservableItem = onlineFriends.makeFriend(data);
onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(newObservableItem);
```

Comment: there is still one final problem. it also pushes the socket data into the array......so i get two items in the array

Comment: this is the data i receive : {"firstName":"Mfon","id":"2","address":"vgc","bio":"A man’s gotta make at least one bet a day, else he could be walking around lucky and never know it.","country":"Macau S.A.R.","email":"mfon@gmail.com","firstname":"Mfon","gender":"FEMALE","lastname":"Ukim","locked":false,"money":0,"onlinestatus":"ONLINE","password":"mfon","phonenumber":"08023182388","picture":"generic-avatar.jpg","username":"mfon","usertype":"PLAYER"}.....it is also pushed into the array along with the converted one